# How do you add up data from one column if the ID is the same in SQL

Tags: sql

Ok this is my problem:

I need to calculate the adding of a column (call it SHIPPED_QUANTITY) if PO_NUMBER is the same, then i need that calculation to be in a where statement so that the combined number will show SHIPPED_QUANTITY < PO_QUANTITY

for instance

```
PO #               PO_QUANTITY           SHIPPED QUANTITY  

123A               500                    200
123A               500                    300
123B               400                    200
124A               500                    500
125A               1000                   500
125A               1000                  500
```

note that even though PO# 123B is similar, it cannot be included in the calculations, in this case using the data above, i would want 123A, 124A, 125A to NOT show (because SHIPPED QUANTITY would = PO_QUANTITY) But i want 123B to show...so i need to add SHIPPED_QUANTITY where PO# is the same, but only those unique (so i can't add 123A, 123A, 125A, 125A,, that would equal 1500, i need 123A to be added with 123A, and 125A to be added to 125A to get 500 and 1000 respectively)

hope that problem was specific enough

oh all must be done in sql, not mysql or oracle sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all rows for the same `PO #` have the same value for `PO_QUANTITY`(*):

```
SELECT
    "PO #",
    MIN(PO_QUANTITY),
    SUM("SHIPPED QUANTITY")
FROM
    UnnamedTable
GROUP BY
    "PO #"
HAVING
    MIN(PO_QUANTITY) > SUM("SHIPPED QUANTITY")
```

(*) What you ought to have is one table for the PO, with just `PO #` and `PO_QUANTITY` and a separate table for the `SHIPPPED QUANTITY`, so that you only store the `PO_QUANTITY` once for each PO.

---

To compose this into a larger query, I'd expect to include the above query as a subquery or (if your database supports them) a Common Table Expression.

For the subquery form, it would look something like:

```
SELECT
    * //TODO - Select columns
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        "PO #",
        MIN(PO_QUANTITY),
        SUM("SHIPPED QUANTITY")
    FROM
        UnnamedTable
    GROUP BY
        "PO #"
    HAVING
        MIN(PO_QUANTITY) > SUM("SHIPPED QUANTITY")
    ) as t(PO,OrderedQuantity,TotalShipped)
//TODO - Rest of query
```

because this avoids having to include other columns in the `GROUP BY` or as aggregates in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: oh i forgot to tell you..all work must be done as a query, and it is all via Views, i am not allowed to alter the tables or views in anyway

Comment: @user1955517 - this is a query. And in standard SQL, as you requested.

Comment: yes it is, sorry it was poorly written response...i only mentioned the part about the not editing tables or views, because it is what i am not allowed to do. 

But your code did the trick, it absolutely worked...I can use this within a larger query correct? So if i wanted to grab more columns...would this fall after a WHERE statement in the larger query, or is it part of the select?

Comment: If you want to include it as part of a larger query (maybe grab some more columns related to the PO?), it may make sense to make it a subquery as part of the `FROM` clause of a larger query - otherwise, you have to mess about with including other columns in the `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT PO_NUMBER, PO_TRACKING_NO, SUPPLIER, PO_QUANTITY, SHIPPED_WT
FROM VW_TRAFFIC_PO_SIDE
WHERE PO_QUANTITY > SHIPPED_WT OR PO_TRACKING_NO = null

that is my query, that i'd like to embedd your query into, and i am having a devil of a time doing it